# how can I prevent system changes w/o Group Policy Object (GPO)?

Tags: rdp, terminal-server, security

I'm getting started with running a terminal server on a virtual private hosted site. The host operator disallows many security systems including access to the group policy editor (GPO). The problem I'm having with this is that my plan had been to lock down the system for a group of users to disallow any access to the system beyond an auto-run of a single application. This doesn't have to be 1000% secure against black-hat hackers, just something that is more trouble than it would be worth for somebody to go browsing around the system or start using the terminal server as their cloud desktop.
I had been using:
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Windows-Terminal-Services-Run-Single-Application.html
as a guide, however, this utilizes GPO which as a local administrator I don't have access to... :(
Anybody have any suggestions on how I can do this?
Cheers,
Andrew

Comment: the server is Windows 2008 r2.

Comment: So, you can't run gpedit.msc?